# How to run or integrate Shell scripts in Chef

Tags: shell, chef

I have developed many automation solutions as shell scripts and it has been successfully being used in Prod/Dev environments.
With Chef being introduced, I need to start using Chef as a future automation solution.

As a First Step, I am trying to integrate existing shell script solution to run within Chef and then convert the shellcodes to the chef at the later point.

I am new to Chef and have taken the basic fundamental course.
So, Please help me how to run the existing shell scripts in Chef as a starting point.

I just need some basic examples, so that I can start to build from there.

Comment: Just search: https://docs.chef.io/resource_script.html

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html,

```
execute 'my_script1' do
  command '/usr/local/bin/script1.sh'
end
```

This will call your script on each chef run.

Comment: Thanks Jason. To run above, i need to create cookbook and its respective resources,recipes etc., directories right?
I may need step by step example with very simple example to understand the start to end including chef directories and its files involved.

Comment: A step-by-step on how to create a cookbook is a bit large in scope here, you can find lots of tutorials on Youtube or around the internet.  

Basically you'd have a cookbook that has a metadata.rb (see the examples), a 'files/default' directory and a 'recipes/default.rb' file.

You'd put your script in files/default/.

In default.rb, which would have a 'cookbook_file' resource that places the script onto the host, and the above execute command. You'd then upload the cookbook to the chef server and add recipe[COOKBOOKNAME] to the runlist of your node.